# loop is taking only last item

Tags: python, list, loops, append

In python 3.x I want to run the while loop for all the elements of mass_list and the output should also be in a list. but my loop is taking only the last value.

input:

```
mass_list = [1969,100756]
```

expected output:

```
 [966,50346]
```

my code is---

```
for a in mass_list:
    mass_sum = 0
    total_mass_sum = []
    while a >= 6:
        i = (int (a/3)-2) 
        mass_sum = i+mass_sum
        a = i
total_mass_sum.append(mass_sum)
print(total_mass_sum)
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please _indent_ your code. It is syntactically incorrect. It is also unclear what you are trying to do with each element.

Comment: `total_mass_sum(mass_sum)= [966,50346]` I don't believe that's valid Python.

Comment: Okey..thanks for pointing out..I am a newbie...will keep that point in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization of `total_mass_sum` must be outside the `for` loop in order to prevent reseting of the output payload for each iteration and the append to `total_mass_sum` must be inside the `for` loop:

```
mass_list = [1969,100756]                     
total_mass_sum = []                           
for a in mass_list:                           
    mass_sum = 0                              
    while a >= 6:                             
        i = (int (a/3)-2)                     
        mass_sum = i+mass_sum                 
        a = i                                 
    total_mass_sum.append(mass_sum)          

print(total_mass_sum) # output: [966, 50346]
```